# PHP Monthly booking

Tags: php, algorithm

We need to create a monthly booking system.

For example:
Now, the month is Oct.

Someone booked a hotel from: `01.11.2018 to: 01.02.2019.`

It means that hotel number is busy: `Nov, Dec, Jan.`

So in list for booking we need something like this:

```
<?php
$array = [
    [
        'month' => Oct,
        'status' => 'free'
    ],
    [
        'month' => Now,
        'status' => 'busy'
    ],
    [
        'month' => Dec,
        'status' => 'busy'
    ],
    [
        'month' => Jan,
        'status' => 'busy'
    ],
    [
        'month' => Feb,
        'status' => 'free'
    ],
]
```

?>

We have date in DB:

```
Start_date -> 01.11.2018

End_date -> 01.02.2019.
```

And we need to show user list months to book, from current `month + 5 months`;

Maybe someone can help us with this algorithm?

Comment: I suppose the array is produced quering a db table. Normally you must have a status for the hotel numbers and change it to busy if someone book it and just take data from db will show the status of each number.

Comment: Is this a question about PHP or some SQL query? I suggest you edit you question and at least show some effort you have made. Please read [How do I as a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Can you show some sample of your code? With the array only, is diifficult to help you. I can suggest to check the database daily to verify if there is any reservation, then show the data to the user to show the status.

Answer (score 0):

Build auxiliary calendar table with generated facts about every date for as many years you want in future. Use those facts to display information in the user interface.

For example

```
Start_date -> 01.11.2018
End_date -> 01.02.2019.
```

You can show information for every day from that range.
Business day, holiday, weekend, **booked** etc.